# concat char+integer in loop

Tags: c, concatenation

I am using the embedded C,

```
double bmenge[20];
```

I have these sentences used many times in my code:

```
 fmasccfp.bmen01 = bmenge[0];
 fmasccfp.bmen02 = bmenge[1];
 ....
 ....
 fmasccfp.bmen20 = bmenge[19];
```

`fmasccfp` is a struct with many other fields, `bmen%i` are the struct fields.

I would like to put these lines in a loop for:

```
char count_field_number (int k )
{
    char buffer_cat[20];
    if (k <10)
    {
        sprintf(buffer_cat, "fmasccfp.bmen0%d",k+1);
    }
    else 
    {
        sprintf(buffer_cat, "fmasccfp.bmen%d",k+1); 
    }                       
    return buffer_cat;
}
```

in the main:

```
  for ( int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
  {  
    buffer_cat = count_field_number(k);
    buffer_cat = bmenge[k];
  }
```

I know that I cannot assign type 'double' to type 'char[20]'.

Could you please help?

Comment: Your data structure, `fmasccfp` (variable name, not type) is badly designed.  You've got an array in it, but the elements are individually named.  That's a complete and utter pain to use.  You can probably treat `&fmasccfp.bmen01` as the starting point of an array indexed from zero.  It will work on all systems I know of, but probably isn't guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @JonathanLeffler remark about the design of your structure.
However, to answer your question, I would use a pointer to go through the contiguous fields:

```
double * bmen = &fmasccfp.bmen01;
for(size_t i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    *bmen = bmenge[i]; 
    bmen++;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

```
char buffer_cat[20];
```

is not one character, you can't use `return buffer_cat;`, it will basically return a POINTER to the first character, but it's returning a CHAR so the value will be between 0 to 255.
The function should be:

```
char* count_field_number(int k)
```

because you're returning a char POINTER, a pointer to that array of characters.
Now, you CAN'T return a pointer, well you can, but it's useless, supposedly - the memory is lost. The array content will probably still be there BUT it is allocated in the stack memory so the memory is freed after the function returns - you should allocate it DYNAMICALLY, so it WILL stay anyway, even after the function returns. Do it the following way:

```
char* buffer_cat = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

when `malloc()` is basically a function that allocates the number of bytes you requested. I've requested 20 times the sizeof(char) bytes, which is basically 20 as sizeof(char) is always 1 byte. This way the memory will not be freed when the function returns, but you will need to free it manually when you're done with it using the function `free()` when the parameter is the pointer (`free(buffer_cat);`).
What's the purpose in the for loop?

```
 buffer_cat = count_field_number(k);
 buffer_cat = bmenge[k];
```

You lose the return value of `count_field_number()` call and rewrite it with bmenge[k].
When you're saying `buffer_cat = bmenge[k];` the compiler takes it as granted and assigns double to pointer and not the double value to that string CONTENT - it won't assign the double to what the string is (`fmasccfp.bmen01` for example). You can't execute unknown commands in the middle of a program in C, as much as I know, you can probably somehow implement it though, it's really complicated, I'd say.
Instead of this, I would just assign `bmenge[k]` to that address in memory using pointers. Let's say `bmen01` and `bmen02`up to 20 are doubles - I'd use a `double* my_double_pointer` (a pointer to a double location in memory), assigning it to `&fmasccfp.bmen01` (address of that double) and then assign `*my_double_pointer = bmenge[k];` (assigning `bmenge[k]` to wherever my_double_pointer is pointing towards) and increment it `my_double_pointer++;` in a loop, no need for any function. This will work as long the variables are declared one after another in that struct, `bmen01` to `bmen20` according to the order.

It will basically just assign `bmenge[k]` to `bmen01` and then it will increment it with the `sizeof(double);` what means that it'll skip that double (`bmen01`) and go on to the next variable (`bmen02`).

Anyway, why didn't you make `double bmen[20];` array in the struct for easier use ?

Comment: -1: _First, is it really C ? You can't declare a local integer inside of a for loop in C._: This is false. The standard C (C99 and C11) allows to declare locale variables inside a for loop.